# IsNull function inside an IIf() not working - MS Access

Tags: mysql, date, ms-access, isnull

I have a field in a query that is checking how the user entered the date on the main form. I am trying to make it like a single entered date when the first text box is fill in and like a **date range** if an ending date is entered into the second text box. So if the ending date text box is blank, it should be ignored and the query should run as if filtering only on a specific date. I used the below expression and only entered the starting date, so it should only consider the field as being filtered by 1 date, not a range. But the query returns blank. `[Text0]` is the starting date and `[Text3]` is the ending date. The field is a job date field intended to only return job numbers from either that date or inside the date range.

Example: If `[Text0]` is set to 4/20/2015 and `[Text3]` is blank, the query should return job numbers A-18, B-18, and C-18. If `[Text0]` is set to 4/20/2015 and `[Text3]` is set to 4/27/2015, the query should return A-18, B-18, C-18, D-19, E-19, F-19. The difference between -18 and -19 is the week that it corresponds to.

```
=IIf((IsNull([Forms]![MainForm]![Text3])=True),[Forms]![MainForm]![Text0],Between [Forms]![MainForm]![Text0] And [Forms]![MainForm]![Text3])
```

Comment: Give us some sample data to work with. I already see what's wrong but I need to make sure the `Between` will work in the context you're using it.

Comment: @Invent-Animate does that help? And thanks for your help again! I think I remember you from a different question :)

Comment: No problem! I need you to understand though, that in the context of your question, we have **no idea** what `job numbers` are or why they should be returned.

Comment: Is this used in VBA or SQL?

Comment: This is SQL, although I primarily keep it in Design view (MS Access). Job numbers are the names for carrying out a specific project. The suffix attached to this job number changes every week (hence the -18 vs. the -19). They are associated with a bunch of information in a lot of tables. One field in one of these tables is the Monday that the job is running - the job date.

Comment: I think the next question is, if `Text3` is empty, does the query search for all records greater than `Text0`? If so, I have a solution, and if not I also have a solution.

Comment: @Invent-Animate it will not return jobs with a text greater than `[Text0]`. Using only the starting date means you will only find jobs with that specific job date.

Comment: Oh! Did not know that. Brian Pessler's solution should be what you need I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is something like this:

```
Select JobNumber, ...
from Jobs
where JobDate >= [Forms]![MainForm]![Text0]
    and JobDate <= nz([Forms]![MainForm]![Text3],[Forms]![MainForm]![Text0])
```